# Annihilator Method. Getting wrong answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, higher-order-logic

[I am doing by this method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT77w.jpg)

Annihilate this function: $(7x^2+5)e^{2x}.$

I am getting the answer $(D^2-2)^5$, but this doesn't annihilate the function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your work for getting $(D^{2}-2)^{5}$

Comment: @DanielGeyfman I have added the picture of method I am doing

Answer (score 0):

You have trivial computation errors,
$$
D^2-4D+4=(D-2)^2
$$
and
$$
(x^a)^b=x^{a·b}.
$$
But you are starting from the wrong general formula, if there are no trigonometric functions involved, you do not use the quadratic polynomial, for $x^me^{\lambda x}$ the annihilator is
$$
(D-λ)^{m+1}
$$

The reason for the difference is that in the trigonometric case the differential operator annihilates two exponential terms with complex conjugate exponential factors at once. Then the annihilator is the product of the two corresponding exponential annihilators,
$$
(D-(\alpha+i\beta))^{m+1}(D-(\alpha-i\beta))^{m+1}
=((D-α)^2+β^2)^{m+1}=(D^2-2αD+α^2+β^2)^{m+1}.
$$

Comment: So, the answer should be (D-2)^3?? But it still doesn't annihilate the function.